# Django Rest Framework block GET requests from external origin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework API with a requirement of blocking GET requests from external sources, kind of similar to how CORS blocks all non-safe verbs. What I need to do is when a GET request comes in from somewhere other than my domain I need to return a 403 Response.

From what I've read about CORS, it can't block GET requests, and I'm not seeing any other built-in options for DRF. I've tried looking at the `request` object to check for an origin but am not seeing that either. Any suggestions?

Comment: did use request or requests

Comment: the request object supplied by DRF. I'm not trying to make a request, but rather get the request origin that was received by my API.

Comment: can you try my below answer

Comment: how do you block cross-origin requests right now - do you use `django-cors-headers`? It has the `CORS_ALLOW_METHODS` options that can be set empty.

Comment: @hoefling unfortunately a GET request isn't usually preflighted so it doesn't trigger CORS check

Comment: @awwester ok, now I start to understand. The real question is what will you do if I don't pass any domain information to you, or query your REST endpoint behind a proxy.

Comment: Hi @awwester I'm currently dealing with the same issue. Did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score -1):

you can try **requests** package,in virtual env install **requests** package

> pip install requests

sample GET requests to getting current exchange rate

```
import requests
currencies_out = requests.get(
        str.format('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id={}', 'e034f1ad6bb44668b6a5c815fe244455'))
if currencies_out.status_code == 200:
     currencies = currencies_out.json()
```